# Capturing the Application Delete or uninstall event in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to be able to delete a user account from a database on a server when a user deletes our iPhone application. What is the best way to capture the delete process. When the user holds down a finger on the application and the big "X" appears. The user presses it and the user is prompted to confirm the deletion of the application. I want to be able to capture the process and clean up the server database of users before the application is actually deleted.
 What method is called when you delete an application? Any thoughts?

Comment: +1 This is certainly a valid question, I wonder who downvoted this without providing any comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not let you do such a thing. It cannot be done.

I suggest you mark an account for inactivity instead, or use some other solution.